# Delphi/Lazarus Filter MSAccess data by SQL Query using DateTimePicker

Tags: sql, delphi, datetimepicker, lazarus

I would like to filter data from MS Access and get them to the LazReport.
I tried few combinations of code but none of them worked. I am still getting error "Types of data does not equal in critteria expression".
MS Access field is set to Date/Time with format Short Date (01.01.2017).
DateTimePicker is set to YMD (Year, Month, Day).

This is my code:

```
procedure TForm12.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    If ListBox1.ItemIndex=0 then
    ReportSelected.Caption:=Listbox1.Items[Listbox1.ItemIndex];

    If ListBox1.ItemIndex=1 then
    ReportSelected.Caption:=Listbox1.Items[Listbox1.ItemIndex];

    If ListBox1.ItemIndex=2 then
    ReportSelected.Caption:=Listbox1.Items[Listbox1.ItemIndex];

    If ListBox1.ItemIndex=3 then
    ReportSelected.Caption:=Listbox1.Items[Listbox1.ItemIndex];

    If (ReportSelected.Caption='Production Overview') And (DBLookUpListBox1.ItemIndex <> -1) And (CboShift.ItemIndex = 0) then
      begin
       SQLQuery_ReportShift.Active:=true;
       SQLQuery_ReportShift.Close();
       SQLQuery_ReportShift.SQL.Text:='SELECT ProductionDate, Shift,    AssemblyLine, Product, OperatorsAvailable, ProductionTime, CleanProductionTime,  DowntimeTime, GoodParts, ScrapTotal, ScrapRate, QualityRate, Availability, Performance, OEE   FROM ProductionInfo WHERE  AssemblyLine='''+DBLookUpListBox1.Items[DBLookUpListBox1.Itemindex]+''' AND        ProductionDate='''+FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy', DateTimePicker1.Date)+'''';
       SQLQuery_ReportShift.Open();

   frReport1.LoadFromFile('ProductionOverview.lrf');
   frReport1.ShowReport;
 end;
```

Comment: Why the `mysql` tag?  You say you are working with an MS Access table.

Comment: Does your machine use '.' as it's global Date separator? '/' is more usual. You may need to use the threadsafe form of FormatDateTime and set up the format setting to those required by MS Access.

Comment: Try this:  Place a TDBLabel on your form, connect it to your ProductionDate field and tell us exactly what it displays.

Comment: It displays exactly the same what it is in database "01.01.2017".
I also tried WHERE ProductionDate=#2017/01/01#; which is working.

Comment: Use parameters or use `'#' + FormatDateTime('yyyy-MM-dd', DateTimePicker1.Date) + '#'`

Comment: I tried your advice. I updated querry: `SQLQuery_ReportShift.SQL.Text:='SELECT ProductionDate, Shift, AssemblyLine FROM ProductionInfo WHERE AssemblyLine='''+DBLookUpListBox1.Items[DBLookUpListBox1.Itemindex]+''' AND ProductionDate=''''#'+FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd', DateTimePicker1.Date)+'#''''';` I got error Syntax error (operator missing) in query expression AssemblyLine='005' AND ProductionDate=''#2017.01.01#''
I tried few FormatDateTime variants but none of them worked. I am really stuck.

Comment: read my comment again. the format is `yyyy-MM-dd`. and no need for the single quotes around it.

Comment: I wrote that I tried few FormatDateTime variants.
I tried this `ProductionDate='''+FormatDateTime('yyyy-MM-dd', DateTimePicker1.Date)+'''';` and also this: `AND ProductionDate='''#+FormatDateTime('yyyy-MM-dd', DateTimePicker1.Date)+#'''';` and this to `ProductionDate='''+FormatDateTime('yyyy-MM-dd', DateTimePicker1.Date)+'''';` and also this: `AND ProductionDate=''''#'+FormatDateTime('yyyy-MM-dd', DateTimePicker1.Date)+'#''''';` none of it worked.

Comment: sadly you fail to read what I wrote in my comments. try: `ProductionDate=#' + FormatDateTime('yyyy-MM-dd', DateTimePicker1.Date) + '#'`

Comment: As I see, you are right. It did not occure to me where should I put those '#'. Its really working. You can add your comment as an answer to this topic so I can accept it as solved. I really appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly Access uses the date in the order Y/M/D and puts '#' characters around it:

```
function AccessDate(d:TDateTime) : string;
var
  yy,mm,dd : word;
begin
  DecodeDate(d, yy,mm,dd);
  result := Format('#%d/%d/%d#', [yy,mm,dd]);
end;
```

As for DateTimePicker to return only date: Turn off time parts by checking dtpHour, dtpMinute and dtpSecond in HideDateTimeParts.

Comment: I suppose that I have to assign this function to DateTimePicker on event FormShow am I right? Then when I use this DateTimePicker in Query it should work...

Comment: @Revan31:  No, you would use the `AccessDate` function to construct the Sql query.

Comment: Hmm I never came along such query. Can you please point me in or update my query with this function?

Comment: I was talking about your `SQLQuery_ReportShift.SQL.Text:= ...`

Comment: Yes I know. I updated it like this:
 `SQLQuery_ReportShift.SQL.Text:='SELECT ProductionDate, Shift, AssemblyLine, Product, OperatorsAvailable, ProductionTime, CleanProductionTime, DowntimeTime, GoodParts, ScrapTotal, ScrapRate, QualityRate, Availability, Performance, OEE FROM ProductionInfo WHERE AssemblyLine='''+DBLookUpListBox1.Items[DBLookUpListBox1.Itemindex]+''' AND ProductionDate='''+AccessDate(DateTimePicker1.Date)+'''';`
but I get the same error "Types of data does not equal in critteria expression".